# Run mysqldump command by php script in xampp but empty .sql

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I need to run this command in php to get my DB backup automatic.

```
<?php
    $output = exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -p > my_db.sql"); 
?>
```

need help

Comment: this command work in CMD but not in PHP  exec

Comment: mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-p` flag requires you to enter a password for the user. Since you are using the default configuration (no password) you should remove the flag.

```
exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root > my_db.sql");
```

with that flag it will just hang waiting for you to pass in the password.

If your user had a password you could do:

```
$output = exec("C:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -pMyPassword > my_db.sql");
```

but this is bad idea because if the script is ever exposed your root password will be known.